# Is there a way of trimming unnecessary zeros in a Number in DataWeave 2.0?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule4

I have a question. Can I trim a number like this: `423230000000` to `42323` using DataWeave expressions?

I have tried a few things but none of them are working.

Comment: Based on what requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I have never hear of zeros to the right of a number being unnecessary. They are mathematically significant, so I'm guessing you have very particular requirements.

In any case if you absolutely have to do it, you could use this function:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var value=423230000000
fun removeLastZeros(x: String) =
    (if (x[-1] == "0") removeLastZeros(x[0 to -2]) else x) as Number
---
removeLastZeros(value)
```

Output: `42323`

Answer (score 0):

As what others have mentioned, if this is really needed you can do the following:

1. treat the number as string
2. reverse it and convert it back to number (making the 0 insignificant)
3. treat the resulting number as string and reverse it again
4. convert the final string to number (if you need it as number)

See sample code below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var payload = 423230000000
---
((payload as String)[-1 to 0] as Number as String)[-1 to 0] as Number
```

This will result to `42323`.